# Linq joins and groups

Tags: linq, join, linq-group

Following on from my previous question: [Simple inner join in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994210/simple-inner-join-in-linq)

How would I write some linq to do exactly the same as the below..

```
SELECT A.name, B.name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.AID 
INNER JOIN C ON B.id = C.BID
GROUP BY A.Name, B.Name
ORDER BY A.Name
```

I've tried this but it generates nested selects and thus produces a different number of rows.

```
var r = from a in db.A
join b in db.B on a.Id equals b.AId
join c in db.C on b.Id equals c.BId
group c by c.B into g1
group b by g1.Key.A into g2
select g2.Key;
```

I need a group of `A`'s that contains a list of `B`'s which contains a list of `C`'s

Comment: you can use a let binding in a linq statement to hold a value. 
from a in db.a
let g1 = a.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
from item in g1
let g2 = item.GroupdBy(x => x.Id)
from item2 in g2
select new {A = a, B = item, C = item2}

or something like that, hopefully it gives you enough to work it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah my comment lost its formatting

you can use a let binding in a linq statement to hold a value.

```
from a in db.a
let g1 = a.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
from item in g1
let g2 = item.GroupdBy(x => x.Id)
from item2 in g2
select new {A = a, B = item, C = item2}
```

or something like that, hopefully it gives you enough to work it out

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a solution.